# makefile rule to build multiple targets without intermediate file

Tags: gnu-make

I am stumped coming up with a makefile rule to have several executables where each depends on its respective source file.  There is a library common to all and each program has a single source file:   `a.c` compiled and linked with the library produces executable `a`, etc.

```
LIB_C_FILES = f1.c f2.c f3.c
LIB_H_FILES = f1.h f2.h f3.h
TARGETS = a b c
CFLAGS = -g -O0 -DDEBUG

.PHONY : all clean

.c.o:
    g++ -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

all:    $(TARGETS)

${TARGETS} : lib.a ${@:%=%.c}
        g++ $(CFLAGS) ${@:=.c} -o $@ lib.a

lib.a:  ${LIB_C_FILES:.c=.o}  $(LIB_H_FILES)
        ar r $@ $?
```

The library portion works fine.  And when an executable does not exist, it also works fine.  But when one of the standalone source files is modified it says `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`

I don't understand the proper way to make target `a` depend on source `a.c` individually in a list.  What am I missing?

Comment: For the record: this question had an overzealous edit.  The question used capital ".C" extensions for C files throughout.  This explains some of the confusion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I assume fio.a was a typo (you probably meant lib.a).

Second, I think the tricky part is your ${@:%=%.c} prerequisite.  AFAIK, $@ can't be used this way.

I think you can get the behavior you're looking for using .SECONDEXPANSION though.

Try:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
${TARGETS} : lib.a $$(patsubst %,%.c,$$@)
```

There may be an old-style substitution way to do this, but I find the patsubst line to be more readable than ${@:%=%.c}.

(I should add that this applies to Gnu make 3.82.  YMMV with older versions of Gnu make, or [heaven forbid] non-Gnu versions of make).

Comment: Indeed, `fio.a` should be `lib.a`.  Names were changed to protect the innocent.  I have never encountered [`SECONDEXPANSION`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) before.  I am indeed using make 3.82 so will give it a try.

Comment: Yay!  It works!  Any idea what that expands into?  It would seem like it was very similar to my rule....

Comment: Without .SECONDEXPANSION, make tries to expand $@ before the targets are known.  With .SECONDEXPANSION, $$@ expands to $@ on the first pass, then once the targets are known, $@ can be expanded as expected.

Comment: @bobbogo I do find your static pattern rule simpler to understand than my .SECONDEXPANSION method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: you can do what you want with plain old static pattern rules, so long as you can match all of `${TARGETS}` with make's (noddy) pattern matching.

```
${TARGETS}: %: %.C lib.a
    g++ ${CFLAGS} $< -o $@ lib.a

lib.a: ...
    ar ...
```

A tad more readable, and perhaps more compatible than `.SECONDEXPANSION`?

Comment: Thanks.  It is more readable, but alas exhibits the original problem:  Updating `a.c` does not trigger the rule.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo above (too late to edit).  It is indeed `a.C`.

Comment: @wallyk: Hmmm, not sure I believe you---there must be something subtle in your environment (are you on a proper Linux box, or is this cygwin/migw &c.?). Try `make -Rr -d --warn all`.

Comment: It is Linux Fedora 16 (32-bit flavor) and GNU Make 3.82.  What does the multiple colon sequence mean?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: It's a _static pattern rule_ (see the [Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)). Basically, these are exactly the same as a normal rule, but give you the opportunity to specify dependencies using `%` as the wildcard.

(Again, for completeness: in the recipe you can use `$*` to expand to whatever text matched the `%` in the rule.) These are _much_ nicer than pattern rules (or "implicit rules" as the make manual would have it), and an under-used area of make IMHO.